# Is there any possibility to use Gradient Map (as one in photoshop) for image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, dictionary, gradient, photoshop

i just wonder is there a possibility to use gradient map as for in image in CSS?

Belove the results i would like to achieve:
https://tomb.pl/projects/cephtactics/images/dentistry.png

Comment: try css filter properties

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg-to-create-a-duotone-image-effect/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a generator for it :)

https://cssduotone.com